# TFileStream and operating with String

Tags: delphi, tfilestream

I am trying to write and read a non-fixed string using TFileStream. I am getting an *access violation* error though. Here is my code:

```
// Saving a file
  (...)
  count:=p.Tags.Count; // Number of lines to save (Tags is a TStringList)
  FS.Write(count, SizeOf(integer));
  for j := 0 to p.Tags.Count-1 do
  begin
    str:=p.Tags.Strings[j];
    tmp:=Length(str)*SizeOf(char);
    FS.Write(tmp, SizeOf(Integer));
    FS.Write(str[1], Length(str)*SizeOf(char));
  end;

// Loading a file
  (...)
  p.Tags.Add('hoho'); // Check if Tags is created. This doesn't throw an error.
  Read(TagsCount, SizeOf(integer)); // Number of lines to read
  for j := 0 to TagsCount-1 do
  begin
    Read(len, SizeOf(Integer)); // length of this line of text
    SetLength(str, len); // don't know if I have to do this
    Read(str, len); // No error, but str has "inaccessible value" in watch list
    p.Tags.Add(str); // Throws error
  end;
```

The file seems to save just fine, when I open it with a hexeditor, I can find the right strings saved there, but loading is throwing errors.

Could you help me out?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You save the number of *bytes*, and that's how many *bytes* you write. When you read the value, you treat it as the number of *characters*, and then read that many *bytes*. That won't cause the problem you're seeing now, though, since you're making the buffer *bigger* than it needs to be as of Delphi 2009.

The problem is that you're reading into the string variable, not the string's contents. You used `str[1]` when writing; do the same when reading. Otherwise, you're overwriting the string reference that you allocated when you called `SetLength`.

```
Read(nBytes, SizeOf(Integer));
nChars := nBytes div SieOf(Char);
SetLength(str, nChars);
Read(str[1], nBytes);
```

And yes, you *do* need to call `SetLength`. `Read` doesn't know what its reading into, so it has no way of knowing that it needs to set the size to anything in advance.